# Is a bottle of wine = a wine bottle?

Tags: nouns

Is this correct that **a bottle of wine** means the same as **a wine bottle**?

For example:

1) I found a bottle of wine
2) I found a wine bottle

This question is about "Noun Chains" or "Compound Nouns (n+n)" or Stone Wall construction.
I wonder what **natives** (my mother language is russian) FEEL about these two sentences without additional words (like *empty*) .

Comment: It all depends on context, but generally: Bottle of wine = bottle containing wine; Wine bottle = bottle that _once_ contained wine, but now does not.

Comment: My guess: a *bottle of wine* consists of both a *wine bottle* and the *wine* inside.  For example, there is a coffee can here with some pens in it; but it is no longer a can of coffee.

Comment: Thank you. I felt the same but one very experienced translator insisted that I was wrong.

Comment: This  is very important for me because I listened one natives on youtube and he reckoned that we (Russian or Ukrainian) are using prep. "of" too often - when we must use noun chains. But it is not very well explained in our grammar books. Can you advise me what to read on the subject?

Comment: It's the same thing as in Russian, actually. An empty bottle of wine, an empty box of matches, an empty pack of cigarettes. Пустая пачка сигарет, пустая коробка спичек, пустая бутылка вина.

Comment: It's hard to establish a consistent rule with this sort of thing - for example, a match box would normally be expected to contain matches.

Comment: As to how often to use a compound vs not using a compound, there can be no advice really. This is something you have to feel naturally. How often would you recommend using "коробка спичек" vs "коробка из-под спичек" vs "спичечный коробок"? Even if you take a huge corpus you could at best say, "the last one is used 17% of the time", but you can never say, "use it 17% of the time". That just won't work.

Comment: Lastly, I wouldn't worry about being identified as a non-native speaker because *that's what you in point of fact are*. Nothing wrong with that. However, if you expressly wish to reach native levels of command, then the first thing you should do is strike the word "rule" from your vocabulary. You didn't become a native speaker of Russian by learning rules. You *first* learned Russian and only *then*, years later, learned that there were words like "rule" or "grammar" or "exception" or "irregular" or "adjective" or "sentence". It's the same for acquiring English, or any other tongue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZynyHW2hfw

Comment: Is there the same question with "water bottle" or "water glass" somewhere in this SE?

Answer (score 1):

One (a bottle of wine) directly indicates the contents of the bottle, whereas the other (a wine bottle) indicates the style and **presumed** content, whether empty or containing substance.

Comment: 1) english grammar forum - OK  2) forum of english grammar - OK too  3) forum of grammar of english - :-)  Is this correct that one can use no more than 3 *"OF"* in one phrase?